# Wicket configuration for nashorn

Tags: wicket, nashorn

I recently upgraded my java version from java 1.7 to java 1.8. After the upgrade i am getting this error.

Caused by: ECMAScript Exception: Type Error: Can not find a common class loader for ScriptObject and My Interface.

Which version of wicket do i need to use which supports java 1.8 and nashorn script engine. Also do i need to configure anything related to Script Engine for wicket.

I have tried adding this dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.wicketstuff</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicketstuff-nashorn</artifactId>
             <version>7.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

and ScriptEngineManager sem = new ScriptEngineManager();
        engine = sem.getEngineByName("nashorn");

but i am still getting the same issue.

Please help me fix this issue.

Below is my method

```
private final ScriptEngine engine;
ScriptEngineManager sem = new ScriptEngineManager();
engine = sem.getEngineByName("nashorn");

public <K> K getNewInterface(MyScript myScript){
        ScriptContext ctx = new SimpleScriptContext();
        String script = myScript.getScript();
        if(Strings.isEmpty(script)) {markInvalid(myScript, "Script is empty", null); return null;}
        script += " (function(){return this;})();";
        Object thiz;
        try{
            thiz = engine.eval(script, ctx);
        } catch (ScriptException e){
            markInvalid(myScript, "Can't execute script", e);
            return null;
        }
        if(thiz==null) {markInvalid(myScript, "Script executed, but context is null", null); return null;}
        K ret = (K) ((Invocable)engine).getInterface(thiz, myScript.getScriptInterfaceClass());
        if(ret==null) {
            markInvalid(myScript, "Script executed, but it's incompatible with required interface", null);
            return null;
        }else{
            myScript.setValid(true);
            return ret;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Wicket doesn't need Nashorn. You can use Wicket 1.5/6.x/7.x/8.x with Java 8.

wicketstuff-nashorn is definitely not needed to run Wicket application.

Without the actual error it is hard for us to tell why it is failing.

**Update**: why do you use `new ScriptEngineManager(null)`, i.e. `null` ClassLoader. Better use `new ScriptEngineManager()` and it will use the context class loader which most probably knows about both classes. Or use `new ScriptEngineManager(YourInterface.class.getClassLoader())`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Martin.

Comment: The statement where i am getting the error is  - K ret = (K) ((Invocable)engine).getInterface(thiz, myScript.getScriptInterfaceClass());

Comment: Caused by: ECMAScript Exception: TypeError: Can not find a common class loader for ScriptObject and My Interface.
 at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.error(ECMAErrors.java:57)
 at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.typeError(ECMAErrors.java:213)
 at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.typeError(ECMAErrors.java:185)
 at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.typeError(ECMAErrors.java:172)

Comment: Don't be shy and paste the whole file in your question. One liners like the one above mean nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply again Martin.I have added the method where i am getting the error. Please let me know if you need the whole file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Martin. I am getting the same error even when i do it this way

ScriptEngineManager sem = new ScriptEngineManager();
engine = sem.getEngineByName("nashorn");

   or 
   
engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");